# How to upgrade to Windows 10 without losing Ubuntu or transfer data of Ubuntu to Windows

Tags: dual-boot, windows, windows-10

I run Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS and Windows 8.1 in dual boot. Now I am getting the option to upgrade to Windows 10 but I fear that if I upgrade, it will delete Ubuntu from my system.

How can I upgrade to Windows 10 without losing Ubuntu? I have important data and it will take a lot of time to transfer my data to hard disk.

If there is a possible way to transfer my data from Ubuntu to Windows, it will also help me.

Comment: @muru Thank you for your help. But the post was not so helpful. I do not focus more on losing Ubuntu but on my data. It would be kind of you to tell me a possible way to either keep Ubuntu or transfer my data to Windows  8.

Comment: afaict there's no data loss, just that Windows overwrites the GRUB boot loader. If you really want to transfer your data, get an external disk and back it up properly

Comment: As I mentioned using disk will take lot of my time. But if it is the only way then I would use it. Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Upgrading Windows shouldn't affect Ubuntu, unless you allow the Windows 10 installer to mess with your partitions.  If the Windows 10 installer simply changes the Windows partition, it won't affect the Ubuntu partition; that's pretty straightforward.

That being said...if you care about the data that much, you need backups.  Not just for this occasion, for ALL occasions.  I've heard it said: **There are two types of people: Those who have complete, regularly updated backups of all their important files and software...and those who *will*.**  Anyone who has experienced the sickening horror of a failed hard drive that contained the only copies of their files, will understand the black humor of this saying.

No hardware lasts forever.  Buy an external drive, they're very cheap these days; $70 can get you a good 1TB USB 3.0 drive.  And *back up your important files*.  If your computer got hit by a sledgehammer *right now*, would you pay $70 to have all your files back?  I thought so.

Back Up Your Files.

Comment: Thank you for your so kind advice but muru already explained me these things in his comment without stories.

Comment: Fair enough.  :)  I don't have enough reputation yet to comment on questions/answers other than my own, and I *did* answer the question...didn't I?  :)

Comment: Yes, you did :)

Comment: @Wildcard You only need four rep to comment, have a +1 on me. Small advice, try to keep your answers as simple a possible, they can be a bit long winded, as leon said "stories" people want quick and simple help here

Comment: @markkirby, thanks!  Mostly I like to go long-winded with very useful (I hope), detailed instructions; this answer was an exception and I do take your point.

Comment: Don't get me wrong, it is not you it is what the question askers want. Most are Windows converts with no experience on Ubuntu, they just don't care to read a wall of text answer, anyway, you have comments now, use them for getting to the root of the issue and then answers for the hard facts at the end. Good luck

Answer (score 1):

During the upgrade process Windows will likely tell you whether it's going to modify just its own partition, or also other partitions on your disc. If it only modifies the Windows partition nothing with your bootloader or Ubuntu partition should change.

You can transfer your files from Ubuntu to Windows right from your file manager. If you're using Nautilus, select your Windows partition in the sidebar under "Devices" and move your files to your Windows desktop as you would into any folder.